# Setting Active Sheet via Sheets API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet wherein I'm facilitating multiple rounds of voting.  The spreadsheet  has roughly 20 sheets total.  Each round of voting is it's own sheet, and when current round X is in motion, the sheet for Round X is made active, a second sheet 'Tabulations' is shown, and all other sheets are hidden.

I am using Google Apps Script and I have functions calling and manipulating data in the round sheets.  An example of one of the functions used in the Round X sheets is below:

```
function sendBallot(localCurrentRound) {
  var currentRoundSheet = ss.getSheetByName(localCurrentRound).activate();
 
  var sendBallot = currentRoundSheet.getRange("SendBallot").getValue();

  if (sendBallot == "Yes"){
    var maxNumVotes = currentRoundSheet.getRange("MaxNumVotes").getValue();

    var currentRoundCandidates = getCandidateRoster(localCurrentRound);
    populateBallotQuestions(localCurrentRound, maxNumVotes, currentRoundCandidates);
    
    ss.toast("Ballot Google Form Updated for " + localCurrentRound + "!!");
  }else {
    ss.toast("Send Ballot not ready !!");
  }
}
```

I'd like to minimize the calls to the Spreadsheet service, so I am attempting to use Sheets API.  I've figured out all the batchget and batchUpdate calls, but I cannot figure out how to make the RoundX sheet active.  I looked at the documentation and can't figure out where the Active/SetActive property lies.

Any ideas?

Comment: So are you trying to set active sheet in Sheets API or Spreadsheet service is also an option?  If so , you can use moveActiveSheet.

Comment: You can include the sheet name in the range.

Comment: I am trying to set active sheet in Sheets API.  I would like to avoid the Spreadsheet service if possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Read Values from active sheet with Sheets API version 4

```
function readValuesFromActiveSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const r = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(),`${sh.getName()}!${sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation()}`);
  const o = JSON.parse(r);
  Logger.log(`Range: ${JSON.stringify(o.range)} Values: ${JSON.stringify(o.values)}`)
}

Execution log
1:51:52 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:51:51 PM  Info    Range: "Sheet0!A1:J21" Values: [["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5","COL6","COL7","COL8","COL9","COL10"],["19","4","4","8","10","17","8","7","11","2"],["9","10","7","19","2","7","5","7","7","3"],["7","0","18","14","17","7","2","1","15","1"],["17","2","1","2","9","1","10","15","15","7"],["18","6","10","17","17","18","5","14","12","0"],["11","10","4","0","4","2","5","3","19","18"],["0","2","0","9","9","10","7","18","7","19"],["6","15","12","9","7","14","13","6","17","6"],["8","17","17","16","8","11","5","17","6","12"],["4","10","8","10","19","14","13","16","1","3"],["16","15","1","16","5","12","16","1","6","10"],["4","19","4","4","3","16","6","14","6","9"],["15","13","0","0","5","17","2","7","17","17"],["2","17","9","9","3","15","19","8","11","2"],["0","5","6","2","12","3","0","10","10","17"],["10","11","13","9","18","6","9","14","1","14"],["2","3","12","14","11","2","14","13","6","0"],["9","3","19","11","4","4","0","5","16","10"],["2","16","2","17","4","16","10","5","11","0"],["8","1","11","16","2","5","9","8","12","9"]]
1:51:53 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

#### Read Multiple Sheets

```
function readvalues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sA = ['Sheet0', 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~sA.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  shts.forEach((sh, i) => {
    const r = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), `${shts[i].getName()}!${shts[i].getDataRange().getA1Notation()}`);
    const o = JSON.parse(r);
    Logger.log(`Range: ${JSON.stringify(o.range)} Values: ${JSON.stringify(o.values)}`)
  });
}
```